# Do we have to limit ad request frequency in order to show banner ads across different screens with Flutter Google Admob package (google_mobile_ads)?

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, google-mobile-ads

I am trying to serve banner ads on every screen in my app.
Every screen will trigger a new Admob AdRequest.

Admob supports states that:
*... if users navigate to and from pages with ads in an app over a short period of time, a new ad request should not be made sooner than the recommended 60 second rate.*

Since I am using goole_mobile_ads package, I am unsure if the package itself handles the ad request limitation or If I have to code it myself. The package documentation doesn't mention this and [Flutter youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0d_pbgeeG8) makes it seems as if I can simply load a different banner ads on every page without worrying about ad request limits.

Can someone please advise? Can we just stick an Banner Ads widget in every page without worrying about the request frequency or do we have to cap the frequency ourselves ?

I followed the tutorials and tested the ads internally. Everything is working fine but I have seen apps getting violation warning for various issues after going live so I am trying to prevent that.